# vue router and anchors

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have setup router to accept an anchor tag

```
const router = new VueRouter({
        mode: 'history',
        scrollBehavior: function(to, from, savedPosition) {
            if (to.hash) {
                return {selector: to.hash}
            } else {
                return {x: 0, y: 0}
            }
        },
        routes: routes,
    });
```

This is fine however if I hit refresh on

```
http://localhost/mypage#anchorlocation
```

I get the WSOD, A redriect to the homepage would be fine. How can I catch this?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `vue-router` because it's a server configuration whenever you use `mode: 'history'`

Have a look at https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html with the server configurations of your preference.